# Struts1 ActionForm are Singleton, If Yes, how different request attributes are stored

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, actionform

Struts1 ActionForm are Singleton, If Yes, how different request attributes are stored in Struts Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `ActionForms` are not Singleton.  There is a component (`RequestProcessor`) which parses your request, instantiates a new `ActionForm`, populates it as best as it is able with the request information and then passes it to the `Action` object (and yes, `Actions` can be thought of as Singleton objects)